# XSLT Namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have a basic question about XSLT Namespaces.
XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="myNamespace" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newNode>
            <xsl:value-of select="x:Node1/x:Node2" />
        </newNode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT works correctly when I apply it to:

```
<Node1 xmlns="myNamespace">
    <Node2>ValueIWant</Node2>
</Node1>
```

But it does not find "ValueIWant" when I apply it to:

```
<ns0:Node1 xmlns:ns0="myNamespace">
    <Node2>ValueIWant</Node2>
</ns0:Node1>
```

I feel that I am just missing some basic understanding of XSLT namespaces.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first input file:

```
<Node1 xmlns="myNamespace">
    <Node2>ValueIWant</Node2>
</Node1>
```

you defined the *default namespace* on node Node1. For Node1 and any of its child nodes (unless/until you redefine it in a child node), the empty namespace prefix is bound to `myNamespace`. So both Node1 and Node2 are in `myNamespace`.

In your second input file:

```
<ns0:Node1 xmlns:ns0="myNamespace">
    <Node2>ValueIWant</Node2>
</ns0:Node1>
```

You are defining the namespace prefix ns0 to point to `myNamespace` but you haven't defined a default namespace. So Node1 is in namespace `myNamespace` but Node2 is not in any namespace at all.

You xpath expression `x:Node1/x:Node2` (with prefix `x` bound to `myNamespace`) is looking for elements Node1 with a child Node2 that are **both** in namespace `myNamespace`. In your second input file, Node2 is not in that namespace so the xpath expression doesn't match and you do not get `ValueIWant` as a result.

You can correct the second input file like this:

```
<ns0:Node1 xmlns:ns0="myNamespace">
    <ns0:Node2>ValueIWant</ns0:Node2>
</ns0:Node1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.  I was under the impression that namespaces cascaded to child nodes.  Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Yes, in a way they do. The binding between the prefix (whether it's the empty prefix as in your first input or "ns0" as in your second input) cascades through to child nodes. You don't have to repeat xmlns:ns0="myNamespace" on Node2. But prefixes are separate, so defining the prefix ns0 does nothing to the binding of the empty prefix.